# Laravel - form validation to pass only if certain field is empty

Tags: laravel, forms, validation, request

So I'm building a form and I need specific fields to be empty.

They return an empty string and from other similar questions, I looked for

```php
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class
```

in `Kernel.php` which is commented out by default, I believe.

I don't want to change its behavior since it's a global middleware.

I have tried making them nullable, `string|sometimes`, `present|max:0` yet none of these give me the desired result. I want the validation to pass only if the fields are empty.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Either make a custom validation for this or use the regex validation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-regex

Comment: By the way `\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,` default is not commented.

Comment: Thanks to @Paladin for pointing me, managed to solve my problem with 'regex:/^\s*$/'

Answer (score 0):

So as I understood, you want for specific field to be required, if the other field in form is empty? To achieve that, you can use `required_without` property in `Request validation` like this:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'filed_name' => 'required_without:other_field_name',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'filed_name.required_without' => 'filed_name is required.',
        ];
    }
```

More on validation on official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation).

Comment: I want 2 different fields to be empty but they are not connected. So I will have to use 1 rule for both of them. Believe that required_if is not helpful here. The fields are not directly required, they just need to be empty.